# Is it possible to download road network data from ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to get the roads from ArcGIS for the Chicago region as a shapefile. I just want paths along the road. Is there anyway to export the information from ArcGIS, so I can use it?

Comment: ArcGIS is broad range of products. To which *particular* road network are you referring? Most of Esri's data partners sell their data, and make it available for ArcGIS Online on the condition that it NOT be downloadable.  And there are scores of free sources of US data.

Comment: @Vince I am pretty new to GIS, so I am struggling a little. But I have a csv file with latitude and longitude points that lines up perfectly with the base map called "Streets" on ArcGIS, I need to figure out the street name associated with each point. I thought if I could download the streets as a shapefile I would be able to do a spatial join and get the information associated with each point. I tried downloading sources online, but they didn't line up how I needed them to, but maybe I was looking at the wrong sources

Comment: @I.Jones Which ArcGIS product are you using?  ArcGIS Online?  ArcMap?  ArcGIS Pro?  Something else?  Is it a program or in a browser?

Comment: @Midavalo I am using ArcGIS Pro and its the program

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.